# Worklight - Paho MQTT Javascript: Always timeout on Android device and works in simulator

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, mqtt

I have a Worklight project that uses Paho MQTT Javascript 'mqttws31.js'.

In the simulator everything works fine, but when connecting from a device it always gives me a timeout.

When I connect to the broker through the app called 'MyMQTT' on the device it connects fine. I can't get it to work with Javascript.

I tested if websockets are supported with this code - [Link](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mm.tc.doc/tc10110_.htm)
The webview in the application supports websockets, so that could not be the problem.

I tried several connection options, but it always times out.

Are there some Android permissions I have to add?

I added one of the examples I tried below.

The broker that I use is HiveMQ and I enabled websocket support on port 8000.

I also tried to connect to a public broker - test.mosquitto.org", 80
But that gives me the same results (works in simulator, not on device).

Please help me!

I know that the Cordova plugin would be better than the Javascript version, but I don't find the Cordove MQTT plugin for Cordova 3.1. That could help me out to.

---

```
    var client = new Messaging.Client("192.168.137.2", 8000, "prototype2");
    $(function() {
        $("#publishBtn").click(function() {
            publish("test", "prototype2/testpublish", 1);
        });

        var options = {

            // connection attempt timeout in seconds
            timeout : 5,

            // Gets Called if the connection has successfully been established
            onSuccess : function() {
                $("#console").append(
                        '<br/>' + "Connected to MQTT Broker over Websockets.");

                // client.subscribe("testtopic", {qos: 2});
                client.subscribe("prototype3/testpublish");
            },

    // Gets Called if the connection could not be established
    onFailure : function(message) {
        $("#console").append(
                '<br/>' + "Connection failed: " + message.errorMessage);
    }
};
// Gets called whenever you receive a message for your subscriptions
client.onMessageArrived = function(message) {

    var topic = message.destinationName;

    var message = message.payloadString;

    $("#console").append(
            '<br/>' + 'Message arrived: Topic: ' + topic + ', Message: '
                    + message);

};

// Attempt to connect
client.connect(options);
```

});

Comment: The only version of Android that supports WebSockets natively in WebView is 4.4.   Are you testing on an Android 4.4 device?

Comment: @DavidDhuyveter I am working on a Android 4.3 device (Galaxy note 2). But I tested WebSocket support with the code from the link I put in the question.

Comment: Android 4.3 does not support WebSockets.  Some Android 4.3 devices have a broken version of WebSockets in the WebView, but I don not know of any that have working WebSockets.  What test are you doing exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Android 4.3 and lower, you need a cordova plug-in to provide WebSockets.  There are a number of these around, but most don't implement the features required by MQTT (support for sub-protocols and for binary messages)

One that does is: https://github.com/mkuklis/phonegap-websocket.  With that plug in, mqttws31.js works fine on Android 4.3.

There is currently an issue with installing standard Cordova 3 plugins in Worklight 6.1, which means that when you add the plug-in to your project, you will ned to have to edit the JavaScript provided on Github.  The edit is simple, just change: require() to: cordova.require()

Comment: I'm trying to install the plugin in Worklight, so I copied all the files from src into the Android project. The www (javascript) file, should I copy this in the common folder or in the Android environment? And how to specify the mqttws31.js file should work with the Android plugin?

Comment: Million Thanks for your answer! It just saved my lot of efforts!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you use the [`develop` branch](http://git.eclipse.org/c/paho/org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.javascript.git/tree/?h=develop) of Paho JS client.

The code below is what I've developed for the Eclipse IoT website [demo](http://iot.eclipse.org/demo) ; it works just fine on my Android phone (4.4 though)

```
var client = new Messaging.Client("ws://iot.eclipse.org/ws", "clientId");
client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;
client.connect({
    onSuccess: onConnect
});

function onConnect() {
    // Once a connection has been made, make a subscription and send a message.
    console.log("onConnect");
    client.subscribe("/fosdem/#");
};

function onConnectionLost(responseObject) {
    if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0)
        console.log("onConnectionLost:" + responseObject.errorMessage);
};

function onMessageArrived(message) {
    console.log("onMessageArrived: "+message.destinationName +": " +message.payloadString);
    // my stuff ...
};
```

Comment: I can't test on a 4.4 device, so I will have to implement te Cordova plugin. Thanks!

Comment: FWIW i just tested this code on a 4.2.2 HTC Sensation, and it works fine.